# Merge complex nested JSON and check value in comma separated column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"name":["cream", "hello"], "keywords": ["[pudding, heavy Cream, heavycream, Sourcream]", "[hello, world, hi]"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ingredient":["cream", "hi", "MS"], "Frequency": [5, 10, 23]})
```

I want to merge both the data frame into another where the requirement is, we should not have duplicate value i.e. the new data frame have all the value of df1 plus add the second data frame df2 value if df ingredient value like 'cream' should not exist in df1 'name' field and also not in df1 'keywords' field in exact form, so 'cream' and 'heavy cream' both are different.

Ideally, the result should be like this
[image]

the first two values are directly copied from df1, while the df2 'cream' value exists directly in df1 name so not added again and df2 'hi' value exist in df1 'keywords' so not added meanwhile third 'ms' value is added.

I have written this code, but I feel it's not most optimized

```
df_new = df1.copy()
for ingredient in df2["ingredient"].str.lower():
    if df1["name"].str.contains(ingredient).any():
         df1 = df1.loc[~df1["name"].str.contains(ingredient)]
    else:
        df1["keywords"] = df1["keywords"].astype('str')
        df1["keywords"] = df1["keywords"].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(", "))
        for keyword in df1["keywords"]:
            print(ingredient)
            print(keyword)
            if ingredient not in keyword:
                print("add value")
                df_new = pd.concat([df_new, pd.DataFrame({"name": ingredient, "keywords": ""},index=[0])], ignore_index=True)
```

In the first run, its giving the expected table but on multiple runs, it keeps adding backslash and breaking the code like this
[image]

Can someone please suggest better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution will help and that it is optimized

## Step 1:

```
# Convert keywords column in df1 to lowercase and split into individual keywords
df1['keywords'] = df1['keywords'].str.lower().str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')
```

## Step 2:

```
# Filter df2 based on condition: ingredient not in df1['name'] or df1['keywords']
filtered_df2 = df2[~df2['ingredient'].isin(df1['name']) & ~df2['ingredient'].isin(df1['keywords'].explode())]
```

## Step 3:

```
# Merge df1 and filtered_df2
merged_df = pd.concat([df1, filtered_df2.rename(columns={'ingredient': 'name'})])
```

## Final step and Result:

```
# Reset the index of the merged data frame
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)
merged_df



    name    keywords                                   Frequency
0   cream   [pudding, heavy cream, heavycream, sourcream]   NaN
1   hello   [hello, world, hi]                               NaN
2   MS           NaN                                         23.0
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I don't need 'hi' in row no 2 as its already covered in row no 1 keyword section and it should be dropped as its duplicate

Comment: I just modified it again. Check it again

Comment: @Vineet I saw that it was my mistake and I just figured out the mistakes and modified the code. Check it out.